# Ionic Input Duplicating and Transforming on Click?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a project with an ionic input. For some reason, the input is being duplicated with a css transformation applied when clicked. What is causing this to happen, and how can I fix it so that it does not show?

The gif below is in chrome, but I was able to duplicate it on a physical android device.

[image]

The input html:

```
<ion-input placeholder="Guess" type="{{keyboardType}}" pattern="\\d*" maxlength="{{answerLength}}" clear-input class="guess-input" [(ngModel)]="guess" (keyup.enter)="submitGuess()"></ion-input>
```

Custom CSS class: (I just added the transform: none to try and solve the issue, but since the transform is getting set to the element style it didn't work.)

```
.guess-input{
        margin: 10px 1% 0 0;
        width: 80%;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1.5px solid black;
        transform: none;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple platforms and I was fixing it by..

I put in app.component.ts:

```
constructor(
                ...
                public config: Config,
        ) {
                // all platforms
        this.config.set( 'scrollPadding', false )
        this.config.set( 'scrollAssist', false )
        this.config.set( 'autoFocusAssist', false )
        // android
        this.config.set( 'android', 'scrollAssist', true )
        this.config.set( 'android', 'autoFocusAssist', 'delay' )
           ...
```

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.